# Remove Custom Category From Database (Query)

Tags: attributes, category-attribute

Can any body tell me where is category attribute stored in magento database ? And how could I remove it from MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All category attributes (and products and customer and customer address) are kept in the table `eav_attribute`.
You can identify it by this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'Your code here';
```

If you get only one record as a result then you are save. That's it.
If you get 2 or more it means that the attribute with that code exists for more entities (for example `url_key` will show 2 results).

In this case the difference is made by `entity_type_id` field.
That's the one that determines the entity (category, product, ...)

To get the `entity_type_id` for the category, run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_entity_type` where `entity_type_code` = 'catalog_category';
```

To merge the 2 queries above and always get the result you need you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `eav_entity`
WHERE
    `attribute_code` = 'YOUR CODE HERE' AND
    `entity_type_id` = (SELECT
                           `entity_type_id`
                        FROM
                           `eav_entity_type`
                        WHERE
                           `entity_type_code` = 'catalog_category'
                       )
```

Answer (score 4):

## Simply Run this Query:- For Disable the category from Database

### First Method

***For setting is_active = Yes***

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` SET `value` = '1' WHERE `catalog_category_entity_int`.`entity_id` =5 AND `catalog_category_entity_int`.`attribute_id` = 62;
```

***For setting is_active = No***

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `catalog_category_entity_int`.`entity_id` =5 AND `catalog_category_entity_int`.`attribute_id` = 62;
```

**NOTE:-** Here 62 is an 'attribute_id' of is_active attribute (that you can find in 'eav_attribute table'), so we are using catalog_category_entity_int.attribute_id = 62 in this sql query.

### Second Method

First of all Find `attribute_id` in `eav_attribute` table thats associated with `is_active` and then look for the `attribute_id` value in `catalog_category_entity_int` there you'll find a value (Column in Table) boolean, set **value = 1** for Active and set **value =0** for Deactive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        DELETE FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code='ryman_tuner_radio'
        DELETE FROM eav_attribute_group where attribute_group_name='Company';   
        # DELETE FROM `core_resource` where `code` = 'customcatattrcompany_setup';
```

The following will remove the Attribute from php.

```
        $setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category','custom_company_department');
```